# Is this Transform possible using a Matrix?

Tags: matrix, graphics, geometry, opengl-es-2.0, linear-algebra

I'm trying to take a static list of vertices and, using a matrix, bend them about a circle as shown in the image below. I can find the new vertices using basic geometry, but I'm unsure how to implement it with a matrix, or if it is even possible. I believe, calling the center of the circle 'C' and calling the distance from the vertex to C 'd', that x' = Cx + d*cos(theta) and y' = Cy + d*sin(theta). (Cx and Cy are components of C). However, I don't think that that, in itself, can be converted to a matrix.

[The Transformation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lkg4dM-150paJ67KXNIKYNdQTaJVk5XUfg/view)

For context, I'm making a 3D Snake game. The Snake is made up of segments, and each segment should connect to the next. I have a direction and position for each connection between the segments, so I figured that I could build the segment by connecting each part as shown. However, it would be inefficient to calculate the vertices for each segment on each frame. If I could have the vertices statically listed and then transform it in the model-world matrix, that would be faster, and fit into the method I'm currently using. I included a simple drawing of the Snake (ignore the head) below.

[The Snake](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8BPyvxUeUy6UWJpaDJlZFRfYXM)

If it's not possible, are there any alternatives that can be done using a matrix while giving a similar result?

Comment: It looks like you just need a matrix to represent shift and rotations, which is totally doable using matrixes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

**Skeleton Animation**:
You can actually add a series of bones to the object and just apply rotation to the bones equally to get a perfect curve. This is the easiest way to achieve this. However, not necessarily the fastest way for your case.

**Just Matrix & Weights**:
If the bending is always in this proportion, you have to add weight information to each vertex and then multiply with a matrix with transformation/rotation/scale combination. This will give you better performance compared to Skeleton animation, as every vertex is multiplied using only one matrix and there is no hierarchy.